# How can I have the same sqlx transaction through multiple functions?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have the following simple scenario for a REST API and I'm not sure how should I do it idiomatically in Rust. So basically there's a `get`˙function that returns a variable type `X` from the database. This `get` function currently receives a [`sqlx::MysqlPool`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/type.MySqlPool.html), creates a transaction, runs the queries to get the data, commits, returns it, done. So far so good.

I have multiple endpoints, but for this example let's say there's an `update` function, which should update the record in the database and return the object afterwards.

My problem is that I'm not sure how I can do this properly.

1. I could just do the `update` with one transaction, and reuse the `get` function afterwards, but that would be two separate transactions and so it's theoretically possible that between those transactions an other client updates the same record as well. Also it doesn't seem optimal.
2. Somehow share the same transaction between those functions, but in that case I would need to start the transaction outside of any of these functions, which somehow doesn't feel right.
3. Simply duplicate most of the `get` function's code in the `update` function, but that doesn't seem to be a good idea, specially if I need to do it in 4-5 functions.

How do people get around this issue?

Comment: 4. have `get` take a parameter that's generic over `MysqPool` and `Transaction` (your own trait if needs be, but [`Aquire`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.Acquire.html) seems promising)

Comment: ^ This is probably the way to go. We wrote our own trait for this kind of behavior (not realizing `Acquire` existed).

Comment: Cheers, will try soon!

Comment: @cafce25 How would it work though? I would `begin()` the transaction outside of the get function and pass that tx around? So it would be something like this (not correct code): `let tx = pool.begin();` `update(&tx);` `get(&tx);` `tx.commit();`, so creating and commiting the transaction would both be outside of these functions, even if I don't want to use them together? So when I simply want to run a `get` I would still need to create the tx outside of `get`? Or how can the `get` function know when to create a new tx and when to use an existing one? Same with the commiting part at the end.

Comment: I believe the `Acquire` implementation does the checking internally, so you'd just always `begin()` `commit()` in `get` and pass in a `Transaction` or `Pool`, both of which do implement the trait.